# Как реализовать поиск в ширину при помощи библиотеки JUNG?

Tags: java, swing, графы

Курсовая работа - визуализатор графов. Пишу на Swing. Для представления графа использую JUNG. Вот код поиска в ширину (отдельным классом сделан для того, чтобы можно было работать с алгоритмом пошагово, а с многопоточкой знаком мало).

```
public class BFS {

    public enum Color {
        WHITE,
        GRAY,
        BLACK
    }

    private Graph graph;
    private Queue<Vertex> queue;
    private List<Vertex> adjacencyList;
    private Vertex u, v;
    private Iterator<Vertex> iter;

    public BFS(Graph graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }


    public void solution(Vertex firstVertex) {
        for (Vertex vertex : graph.getVertices()) {
            vertex.setDistance(-1);
            vertex.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        u = firstVertex;
        u.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        u.setDistance(0);
        queue.add(u);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            u = queue.remove();
            for (Iterator<Vertex> i = graph.getSuccessors(u).iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                v = i.next();
                if (v.getColor() == Color.WHITE) {
                    v.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    v.setDistance(u.getDistance() + 1);
                    queue.add(v);
                }
            }
            u.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```

Лишнее постарался убрать.
Поиск не работает. Вообще. Иногда он красит какие-то вершины. Первый запуск для каждой вершини одинаков. Но если запустить поиск из вершины, с которой он уже ранее запускался, то результат иной, нежели был ранее.
Ещё интересно, что при замене проверки цвета на другую, которая должна бы давать идентичный результат,
к примеру:
`if (v.getDistance() < 0)` ,
или хранить словарь вершин и булевых значений, которые показывают, была ли посещена ранее соответствующая вершина,
результат отличается.
Если делать более значимые структурные изменения (хранить свой список вершин, и свои списки смежности),
которые должны бы давать такие же результаты,
дают другие результаты,
но все равно неправильные.
По итогу:
в процесе работы алгоритма, одна вершина обрабатывается по нескольку раз.